# Unable to call ffmpeg in a batch file

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch, batch-file

I reencode a lot of video files with ffmpeg using the following command at the prompt:

```
for %F in ("..\*.*") DO ffmpeg -n -i "%F" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%~nF.mkv"
```

I created a batch file containing this command and put it in my profile path. But when I run it, I get the following:

```
M:\>ff.bat
The following usage of the path operator in batch-parameter
substitution is invalid: %~nF.mkv"

For valid formats type CALL /? or FOR /?
The syntax of the command is incorrect.

M:\>for F" -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a copy "F" -c:v libx265 -crf 28 -c:a copy "%~nF.mkv"
```

A problem with quote marks maybe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### A problem with quote marks maybe?

No. it's a problem with `%`. On the command line use a single `%`. In a batch file  double it up `%%`.

So use the following:

```
for %%F in ("..\*.*") DO ffmpeg -n -i "%%F" -c:v libx265 -c:a copy "%%~nF.mkv"
```

> If you are using the `FOR` command at the command line rather than in a batch program, use just one percent sign: `%G` instead of `%%G`.

Source: [For - Looping commands - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/for.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)

Answer (score 0):

Exactly you have to use double percentage signs instead of single.
Also make sure the ffmpeg paht is in the %path% variabel of you have to specify the whole path to ffmpeg program....

Comment: `%path%` has nothing to do with the problem.